# jqgrid checkbox always checked

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm having some issues with setting up my checkbox in my jquery web app. My json looks like below. I want the deadInd to be a check box (Y or N)...

```
    {
        "userid": "Mike",
        "regname": "xxx219123",
        "noteid": 1040,
        "actiondt": "2014-11-20T00:00:00",
        "fromdt": "2014-11-18T00:00:00",
        "note": "Faulty drawer",
        "reasoncde": "AC",
        "deadind": "N",
        "lastmodified": "2014-11-18T15:38:27"
    },
```

And my column is below. See the deadInd column...

```
colModel:[
    {name:'regname', width: 12, align:'center', sortable:false},
    {name:'reasoncde', width: 10, align:'center', sortable:false, formatter:reasonCodeFormatter},
    {name:'userid', width: 12, align:'center', sortable:false}, 
    {name:'noteid', hidden:true},
    {name:'note', width: 40, align:'left', sortable:false},         
    {name:'fromdt', width: 12, align:'center', sortable:false, formatter:dateToTimestampStringFormatter},
    {name:'actiondt', width: 12, align:'center', sortable:false, formatter:dateToTimestampStringFormatter},
    {name:'deadind', width: 10, align:'center', sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions:{value:"Y:N", defaultValue: "N"}, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions:{disabled: false}  },
    {name:'lastmodified', width: 17, align:'center', sortable:false, formatter:timestampStringFormatter}
],
```

For some reason the checkbox is always ticked. As per my understanding because N is specified as the second value in editOptions I thought my check boxes should be unticked.

Appreciate your help.

thanks

Comment: Ah ok. I assume that's means you'd like a fiddle set up. I'll get one up soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but how shows [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Richie.htm) the value `"deadind": "N"` will be do displayed as unchecked checkbox.

Comment: thanks for that. I've pasted your code into my webpage and for some silly reason my checkbox is still checked!

Comment: I should also mention that I am using jquery 1.7.1. Your version is newer. I'm mentioning this because I've just found another example at my company where the checkbox has been set using a formatter similar to this....function actionFormat( cellvalue, options, rowObject ){
 var bchk = cellvalue.search(/(false|0|no|off)/i)<0 ? " checked='checked' " : "";
 var formatter = "<input type=\"checkbox\" "  + bchk  + " value=\""+ cellvalue +"\" offval=\"no\" " +  " onclick=\"processAction(\'" + options.rowId + "\');\"/>";
 return formatter;
}

Comment: @Richie: You can easy verify on [the modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Richie1.htm) that it's not the reason too. Could you provide the demo which not works?

Comment: Funny thing is that when i changed my checkbox condition to this....editoptions:{value:"YES:NO",defaultValue:"NO"}.... i got what i wanted. Something silly about 'Y:N' that I don't understand. But i guess it doesn't matter too much. I just changed my sql query to do a decode and return YES or NO